# Angular: How to utilize Linky with contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add a clickable link to contenteditable div with the help of linky.

```
ng-bind-html = "model | linky";
```

I haven't been able to make it work as ng-sanitize escapes links. Here is what I think happens:

- Text entered as " http://something.com "
- `linky` wraps this as `<a href="http://something.com">http://something.com</a>`
- `ngSanitize` escapes this again potentially breaking `linky's` implementations

How can I make it work such that links added to `div` are clickable and not escaped html? [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5qbt6B4fuY7GuMyV4oY?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="customControl">
    <h4>How to add link to Contenteditable div?</h4>
 <div contenteditable
      name="myWidget"
      ng-bind-html="userContent"
      ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Change me </div>
  <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required </span>
 <hr>
 Model: <p aria-label="Dynamic textarea">{{userContent}}</p>
</body>
```

**JS Code:**

```
app.directive('contenteditable', ['$sce','$filter', function($sce,$filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html( $sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$evalAsync(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  }]);
```

**UPDATE:**

Currently, am solving this issue with the help of [AutoLinker](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js/)

Replace -

```
ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
```

With

```
var autoLinked = Autolinker.link(html, "_blank");
ngModel.$setViewValue(autoLinked);
```

Check out [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/75hRZnYujytgmVUP9pKu?p=preview)

Comment: see this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3285#issuecomment-21958391

Comment: @TarunDugar Hey I am not trying to use linky to convert html code. I have modified my question to explain what happens.